# Control 2 relays with micropython

Tags: iot, micropython

Can some one help me with a problem.

I have an ESP32 board with GPIO pin 25 and 27 connected to a 2 relay board and with a webserver.

At boot one relay is low and one is high then the code behind the webpage is

```
while True:
  try:
    if gc.mem_free() < 102000:
      gc.collect()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    conn.settimeout(3.0)
    print('Got a connection from %s' % str(addr))
    request = conn.recv(1024)
    conn.settimeout(None)
    request = str(request)
    print('Content = %s' % request)
    relay_on = request.find('/?relay=on')
    relay_off = request.find('/?relay=off')
    if relay_on == 6:
      print('RELAY ON')
      relay_a.value(0)
      relay_b.value(1)
    if relay_off == 6:
      print('RELAY OFF')
      relay_a.value(1)
      relay_b.value(0)
    response = web_page()
    conn.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n')
    conn.send('Content-Type: text/html\n')
    conn.send('Connection: close\n\n')
    conn.sendall(response)
    conn.close()
  except OSError as e:
    conn.close()
    print('Connection closed')
```

but with this cod only relay_a is getting triggered on an off.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) show us your code for pin initialization, i.e.```relay_$ = Pin(2#, Pin.OUT)```. 2) Why to use raw sockets instead of web server? 3) why index is 6? (it should be 4 for GET and 5 for POST, right?)

Comment: Thank you for answers, I solved with webserver config.